# NODEJS and HEROKU : I can't serve the static files once the server is deployed

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, heroku, static-files

ok, I have the simple server which is the following setup:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);

process.env.PWD = process.cwd();

app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD+'/Public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res) {

  res.sendfile(process.env.PWD+ '/index.html');
  res.end;

});
```

I create a git in the folder and I successfully push it to heroku, but when I open it I get this result:

https://leoforio.herokuapp.com/

If you open the console log you will see that it fails to load css and js static files which can't be found,although when I test my app locally this setup works and the files are served as planned.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I don't think it a problem with heroku,I believe the problem is within nodejs and uploading the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem lies in how you're specifying the directory for static files.

What I normally see -- and prefer -- is setting up static this way:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

That means Express will look for the static files in the `public` subdirectory of the *same* directory that your application file is in.  Let's imagine you have two apps, `app1.js` and `app2.js`.  `app1.js` is configured the way you have it, using `process.cwd()` (current working directory), and `app2.js` is using `__dirname` as its base.  Both of these apps are in `/home/drizo/app`.

If you do this, both will work correctly:

```
cd /home/drizo/app
node app1.js              # uses cwd + /public = /home/drizo/app/public
node app2.js              # uses __dirname + /public = /home/drizo/app/public
```

However, if you do it like this:

```
cd /home/drizo           # or ANY directory that's not /home/drizo/app
node app/app1.js             # uses cwd + /public = /home/drizo/public - WRONG
node app/app2.js             # uses __dirname + /public = /home/drizo/app/public
```

As you can see, `app1.js` is using the directory that the app was *started* from.  I'm not sure how Heroku starts/restarts apps, but I'm guessing it isn't doing it from the directory you expect.

Comment: Hey ethan,thanks for answerng!I used your suggestion before the one I use now and it didn't work either.Let me try again and I will tell you!

Comment: It seems to me that heroku or whoever executes the app.js file fails to 'understand' the 'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));' because if you go to console it says that it can;t find the file in the same folder as app.js.

Comment: also consider that the app when it is in my local machine it works fine, when I upload to heroku that is when everything fails!

Comment: Why don't you try logging `__dirname` to the console, and maybe this: `console.log(__dirname); console.log(require('fs').existsSync(__dirname + '/public'));`...if you have access to the console log, it might give you some clues....

Comment: Make sure the `public` subdirectory exists (I see you have it as `Public` with a capital P...non-Windows servers are case sensitive....)

Comment: that is the problem when you are a self-taught programmer like me, you dont know the theoritical stuff. Thanks Ethan sensitivity was the problem for me. check the ling it is up and running!